# Empty results for associated queries

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackauth, associated

Queries such as this

```
http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/f5388585-c0b9-417f-99c5-f1a58fda3e83/associated
```

have started giving empty results

```
{
  "associated_users": []
}
```

---

Expected results:

```
SiteUrl                                                                                                                          UserId      AssociationId                        UserType    DisplayName                                        AboutMe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Location                                                                                                                         WebsiteUrl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       EmailHash                                                        CreationDate            LastAccessDate          TimedPenaltyDate        AcceptRate  Age         AnswerCount DownVoteCount QuestionCount Reputation  UpVoteCount ViewCount   BadgesGold  BadgesSilver BadgesBronze Rank        TimeStamp          GlobalRank  LastUpdated             RowId
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------------------------------ ----------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------- ------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ------------ ----------- ------------------ ----------- ----------------------- -----------
http://superuser.com/                                                                                                            820         F5388585-C0B9-417F-99C5-F1A58FDA3E83 2           heavyd                                             nothing to see here... move along                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Utah                                                                                                                             http://heavyd.net                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                9ccdeef3a9cce3d078f801a092aa40a3                                 2009-07-15 11:59:51.000 2010-09-16 01:55:23.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 71          26          414         56            7             12713       612         522         1           13           29           10          0x000000000065066C 586         2010-09-15 21:17:00.640 444
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/                                                                                                   94928       F5388585-C0B9-417F-99C5-F1A58FDA3E83 2           heavyd                                             nothing to see here... move along                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Utah                                                                                                                             http://heavyd.net                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                9ccdeef3a9cce3d078f801a092aa40a3                                 2009-06-27 00:00:00.000 2010-09-13 18:58:06.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 25          26          19          35            7             1912        391         31          0           5            19           151         0x0000000000641146 6135        2010-09-15 21:07:31.230 4448
http://stackoverflow.com/                                                                                                        94928       F5388585-C0B9-417F-99C5-F1A58FDA3E83 2           heavyd                                             nothing to see here... move along                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Utah                                                                                                                             http://heavyd.net                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                9ccdeef3a9cce3d078f801a092aa40a3                                 2009-04-23 12:02:03.000 2010-09-15 02:37:36.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 67          26          107         17            7             2753        170         176         0           3            14           3724        0x000000000065AAAA 4121        2010-09-15 21:25:32.047 26004
http://serverfault.com/                                                                                                          2904        F5388585-C0B9-417F-99C5-F1A58FDA3E83 2           heavyd                                             nothing to see here... move along                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Utah                                                                                                                             http://heavyd.net                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                9ccdeef3a9cce3d078f801a092aa40a3                                 2009-05-18 02:46:04.000 2010-09-13 13:10:05.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0           26          7           1             3             231         23          63          1           2            12           1747        0x00000000006491E1 33715       2010-09-15 21:10:55.900 64902
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/                                                                                                1409        F5388585-C0B9-417F-99C5-F1A58FDA3E83 2           heavyd                                             nothing to see here... move along                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Utah                                                                                                                             http://heavyd.net                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                9ccdeef3a9cce3d078f801a092aa40a3                                 2010-07-08 03:34:42.000 2010-08-27 21:23:41.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0           26          0           1             0             100         6           0           0           0            3            2643        0x000000000063580A 98942       2010-09-15 18:46:13.840 171739
http://stackapps.com/                                                                                                            195         F5388585-C0B9-417F-99C5-F1A58FDA3E83 2           heavyd                                             nothing to see here... move along                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Utah                                                                                                                             http://heavyd.net                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                9ccdeef3a9cce3d078f801a092aa40a3                                 2010-05-21 00:13:27.000 2010-09-13 12:12:13.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0           26          0           0             0             101         0           0           0           0            1            299         0x000000000063B801 79738       2010-09-15 20:39:57.220 352183
http://ui.stackexchange.com/                                                                                                     1527        F5388585-C0B9-417F-99C5-F1A58FDA3E83 2           heavyd                                             nothing to see here... move along                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Utah                                                                                                                             http://heavyd.net                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                9ccdeef3a9cce3d078f801a092aa40a3                                 2010-09-13 12:14:30.000 2010-09-13 12:14:30.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0           26          0           0             0             101         0           0           0           0            1            849         0x000000000063C70E 98280       2010-09-15 18:53:24.463 358042

(7 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Indeed. And that was exactly what I wanted to use this morning! Trying to nudge some folks...

Comment: The right folks are already actively working on this.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved.

The `/sites` route got some tuning... and then some untuning, and general unpleasantness all around.  As a side effect this route wasn't behaving correctly, and since the `/sites` route sees much more use I only got around to this one an hour or so ago.